# Which can be calculated faster? (Fast Fourier Transform)

Tags: fourier-analysis, computational-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

I am introducing myself in what is Fourier analysis, solving some exercises I ran into a problem that made me curious. Since I don't know much about mathematical formalism, I approached the problem using computational complexity theory or algorithm analysis.

The question is:
Which can be calculated faster?
(A) The FFT for a 96-point signal, or. 
(B) The FFT for an 87-point signal. 
And why?

I was considering a well-known FFT algorithm called radix 2, which reduces the complexity from N² to N log N base two. This algorithm has a multiplication total of **(N / 2) log N**.

So if we consider both cases the complexity in both does not really change so much. In other words, the difference between N = 96 and N = 87 is relatively small.

I wish they could give me a mathematical approach if possible. And in case of being wrong, a correction.

Regards.

Comment: There are a lot of little variations on the FFT algorithm for n with various properties, all of them give you n log(n) time to my understanding, just the prefactor may not be as good if, for example, n is prime compared to when it is a power of 2.